# How to connect hive through play frame work (using hive JDBC)?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, hive, playframework-2.0

I'm newbie to Play framework. Here i am doing the project on connecting with database. I have tried with MySql and got successful output. But i am not able to connect with **Hive JDBC**.

Below are the changes i did.

**build.scala**

```
     name := "SAI"

        version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

        libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.apache.hive" % "hive-jdbc" % "0.13.0",
          Jdbc,
          javaEbean,
          cache,
        "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.5",
        "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13",
        "org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.3.2",
        "org.apache.hive" % "hive-exec" % "0.13.0",
        "org.apache.hive" % "hive-metastore" % "0.13.0",
        "org.apache.hive" % "hive-service" % "0.13.0",
        "org.apache.thrift" % "libfb303" % "0.9.1",
        "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.17",
        "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.1"
        )   
play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

**application.conf**

```
db.default.driver=org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/test"
ebean.default="models.*"
```

While trying to connect, i am getting below error

```
! @6o8kokmi3 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:92)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:570)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:252)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:243)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(enter code hereTraversable.scala:105)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.onStart(DB.scala:243)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)`enter code here`
```

Please let me know any thing i missed  and thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to connect to hive using another client?

Comment: yes i tried that using normal java i am able connect to hive jdbc

Comment: Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: Hi Steve, play 2.2.6 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.7.0_67)